Why did my question get migrated to Health.SE?
I recently asked this question which was migrated to Health Stack Exchange. In my question, I provided an example of an odd phenomenon where the brain would limit the muscles physical capacity to do work, then I asked why this happens? I am interested in answers relating to which mechanisms in the brain limit muscle capacity and what conditions activate those mechanisms.
I included a lot of detail about a medical diagnostic test because it helps illustrate the phenomenon, but I only did that to increase the quality of the question--if I did not do a good job, please provide actionable feedback so I can improve my writing abilities and the question I've asked on this site. I mentioned the acronym TMJ in the title, just to try and be more specific--did that mislead the readers?
How could I improve/alter the question to get it migrated back to Cognitive Sciences SE? 

The mod team migrated that question, because:

The question is a self-help question which makes it explicitly off-topic here (which may actually make it off-topic over at Health as well);
The question is about a pathology of the joints (temporomandibular joint), which is the realm of Biology or Medicine.

In all, it is a question off-topic here, but it was well-sourced and well-researched question so migration was the best option.

Why do you think it is a self-help question? I'm asking about the neurological mechanisms that limit physical output. I don't understand your view.

@Klik - The question is considered self-help in my view because it related to diagnostic testing and final diagnosis for a medical problem you are suffering (TMJ).
